# Javascript checking for float

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I've got an app that users input coordinates into.

In the DB and most mapping software they use the decimal notation for lat/lng (eg. `123.1234`) rather than the older format: `34N 40' 50.12"`

I need to test that a value input into a form is a float, and not a string. But using parseFloat on `34N 40' 50.12"` returns 34-- which validates using most tests.

Here's what I'm trying, which is a mashup of a few really clever solutions found here-- but so far I can't get the thing to work properly for all cases. The basic cases I'm testing for are:

- `123.1234` -- valid
- `'123.1234'` -- valid
- `34N 40' 50.12"` -- invalid
- `'34N 40' 50.12"'` -- invalid
- `123` --valid
- `'123'` -- valid

Here's a jsfiddle of what I've been trying: http://jsfiddle.net/zfwAj/

Comment: `isNaN` should work to filter out those ones: http://jsfiddle.net/QYMRe/

Comment: @JosephMarikle You should add that as an answer, it's the most simple way to test that.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Agree. Put it up and I will upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I should have posted as an answer

[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) should work to filter out those ones [jsfiddle.net/QYMRe](http://jsfiddle.net/QYMRe)

Comment: @Joseph-- simple, and elegant-- exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno You're welcome. :) Glad I could help (lol i commented on the wrong spot... it's late)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^\d+\.?\d*$/.test( str );
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfwAj/2/)

Comment: `/\D/.test('123.45')` // true

Comment: @Jack Thank you. came up with a different expression :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this one:

```
/^-?(\d*\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)$/.test(str)
```

This accepts negative numbers, and float like (.42)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilausuch/8gn9jm95/) test